# Why does an external terminal window open when I run a project in Qt Creator?

Tags: terminal, qt-creator

Usually when I run my Qt projects, all the debug info appears in the Applications pane within Qt Creator. Weirdly my latest project opens a terminal window and puts all the output there instead.

When I quit the app, the terminal window says
`Press <RETURN> to close this window...`
and the window title shows qtcreator_process_stub

Why is this happening and how can I go back to seeing debug info within Qt Creator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Run in terminal` option has been set for this project (for this build kit).

To change the setting within Qt Creator, open the Build & Run kits for the project. (**Projects** tab on sidebar). Select **Run** for the kit you're interested in and, under the heading **Run** you'll see checkbox `Run in terminal`. Uncheck this.

Alternatively open the `.pro.user` file and search for `UseTerminal`. Depending on which version of Qt Creator you're using you'll see a line like this:

`<value type="bool" key="Qt4ProjectManager.Qt4RunConfiguration.UseTerminal">true</value>`

Change `true` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want QT to always run your code in a terminal, go to:

- `Edit > Preferences > Build & Run > Default for 'Run in Terminal'` and select `Disabled`

More info on this [link](https://computerscience.chemeketa.edu/guides/qtcreator-setup/#common-issues).

[image]

From now and on, all projects created, will have their build kit options with `Run in Terminal` unchecked. Projects created before this modification, will not be affected by this general configuration, but they can be manually changed to not run the in a terminal